# Three lines to get twenty triangles

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

Shown below are five squares.

[image: five squares in a cross formation]

Starting at any point, draw *three* straight lines **without lifting the pen**, and create exactly twenty (20) triangles. It is understood that this will create some other shapes also.

> Bonus question: What is the maximum number of triangles you can get
> with the 3 continuous lines (as stated above)? Hint: it is more than
> 26

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the triangles are allowed to overlap, I think I can just Zorro through like this:

> [image]

Counting:

- Triangles with all 3 sides made of grid lines: 0
- Triangles with 2 sides made of grid lines: 12 (4 per each drawn line)
- Triangles with 1 side made of grid lines: 8 (4 for each intersecting red line pair)
- Triangles with 0 sides made of grid lines: 0

---

As for the bonus, here's the best I've found so far (no idea if it's optimal; more than 26 though)

> **28 triangles**
>  [image]

Again counting:

- Triangles with all 3 sides made of grid lines: 0
- Triangles with 2 sides made of grid lines: 17 (6+5+6)
- Triangles with 1 side made of grid lines: 10 (3+4+3)
- Triangles with 0 sides made of grid lines: 1